# rails server BUG Segmentation fault darwin 12.3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

trying to get my ruby app working here, so I ran bundle install and then when I wanted to run my server by rails server I got this huge error log, here is the begining of it.

```
/Users/marcus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
```

Any suggestions what it could be that causes this?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling? How about using Ruby 2.1.2 and seeing if you can reproduce it?

Comment: What is the result of `ruby --version` and `which ruby`? It almost looks like the wrong version of the gem (i.e. of the wrong ruby) is trying to be loaded.